# Get CSS class name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am facing a problem to get the class name from a string in JavaScript.

For example:

```
var ddd="<p class='Box_title'>Heading text here...</p>";
```

Now from that I want to get p tag's class name.

Comment: I think this is a similar post that could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @GoRoS: That is about something totally different.

Comment: Ouh, ok, I've understood wrong the question

Answer (score 14):

Browsers are good in HTML parsing:

```
//setup
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = ddd;

// get the class
var class_name = tmp.children[0].className;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Ejemplo</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
                var ddd="<p class='Box_title'>Heading text here...</p>";
                $('.container').append(ddd);
                alert($('.container').children(':first-child').attr("class"));
        });
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="container">
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   var RegExp = /class='(.+)'/;
   var result = RegExp.exec("<p class='Box_title'>Heading text here...</p>");
```

this will return an array with class name as one of it's elements

Comment: seriously, why would you use regex for this when you've got an HTML parser right there ready to use?

Answer (score -2):

```
var d = "<p class='Box_title'>Heading text here...</p>";
var cls = d.match(/class\=\'(.*)\'/);
alert(cls[1]);
```

This regex will return your class name

Comment: the you are writing it wrong, I have tested it and its working, if you are using firebug, just paste my code into console and run it