# Get name of object or class

Tags: javascript

Is there any solution to get the function name of an object?

```
function alertClassOrObject (o) {
   window.alert(o.objectName); //"myObj" OR "myClass" as a String
}

function myClass () {
   this.foo = function () {
       alertClassOrObject(this);
   }
}

var myObj = new myClass();
myObj.foo();
```

`for (var k in this) {...}` - there is no information about the `className` or `ObjectName`. Is it possible to get one of them?

Comment: You might want to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 484, accepted):

Get your object's [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) function and then inspect its [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name) property.

```
myObj.constructor.name
```

Returns "myClass".

Comment: Beware! If you're minifying the JavaScript the name of the constructor will change.

Comment: Handy, but there's another caveat: if your object has a prototype *chain* (aside from `Object`), you will get the the name of the *first* link in that chain, not the name of the constructor used to create the object. Take the following example: `function Daddy() {}; function Me() {}; Me.prototype = new Daddy; me = new Me;`. `me.constructor.name` then unexpectedly returns `'Daddy'`, not `'Me'`.

Comment: Also worth knowing that the name property is not supported in < IE9

Comment: And this will return empty string, if used on objects declared through variable: `var Foo = function() {};`.

Comment: The Chrome console knows something you don't: 
`> myclass=(function(){}); new myclass` prints
`myclass {}`

Comment: @dB. That's the problem of whoever uses a destructive minifier. More specifically, "JavaScript minifiers such as UglifyJS have destructive mangling options turned on by default. [Selectively] disable these options if you need to preserve certain identifiers and their corresponding constructor names."

Comment: ALSO, this is the constructor name, not objet name

Comment: It works for an only and quite rare case – when you explicitly define the constructor and don’t alter the prototype. In other cases contructor.name is equal to Object or Function.

Comment: and doesn't work when using revealing module pattern?

Comment: @mklement0 If you assign to `Me.prototype` you have to remember to do `Me.prototype.constructor = Me`. Then `new Me().constructor.name` will be `"Me"`. If you're using ES6 classes to do inheritance it will do this for you.

Comment: The `name` property is not supported in Internet Explorer up to IE 11 which is the latest version that will ever exist. So not working in IE.

Comment: I need this several hours before the deadline of an assignment. Glad it worked, thanks!

Comment: returned 'anonymous' when used with the class itself `myClass.constructor.name`

Answer (score 39):

Example:

```js
function Foo () { console.log('Foo function'); }
var f = new Foo();
console.log('f', f.constructor.name); // -> "Foo"

var Bar = function () { console.log('Anonymous function (as Bar)'); };
var b = new Bar();
console.log('b', b.constructor.name); // -> "Bar"

var Abc = function Xyz() { console.log('Xyz function (as Abc)'); };
var a = new Abc();
console.log('a', a.constructor.name); // -> "Xyz"

class Clazz { constructor() { console.log('Clazz class'); } }
var c = new Clazz();
console.log('c', c.constructor.name); // -> "Clazz"

var otherClass = class Cla2 { constructor() { console.log('Cla2 class (as otherClass)'); } }
var c2 = new otherClass();
console.log('c2', c2.constructor.name); // -> "Cla2"
```

Fixed example:

```js
function alertClassOrObject (o) {
   // ::::::: Fixed line
   console.log(o.constructor.name); //"myObj" OR "myClass" as a String
   // ::::::: Fixed line
}

function myClass () {
   this.foo = function () {
       alertClassOrObject(this);
   }
}

var myObj = new myClass();
myObj.foo();
```

Comment: looks like when using the revealing module pattern, you'll always get "Object".   `function Foo() { return {'foo':'bar'} }; var f = new Foo();`  :(

Comment: The 'b' log now outputs "Bar" in FF88 and Node (via https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground). Seems like anonymous functions now inherit their variable name. And, in case you were wondering, classes use the class name used with `new`.

Answer (score 10):

As this was already answered, I just wanted to point out the differences in approaches on getting the constructor of an object in JavaScript.
There is a difference between the constructor and the actual object/class name. If the following adds to the complexity of your decision then maybe you're looking for `instanceof`. Or maybe you should ask yourself "Why am I doing this? Is this really what I am trying to solve?"

**Notes:**

The `obj.constructor.name` is not available on older browsers.
Matching  `(\w+)` should satisfy ES6 style classes.

**Code:**

```
var what = function(obj) {
  return obj.toString().match(/ (\w+)/)[1];
};

var p;

// Normal obj with constructor.
function Entity() {}
p = new Entity();
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name , "class:", what(p));

// Obj with prototype overriden.
function Player() { console.warn('Player constructor called.'); }
Player.prototype = new Entity();
p = new Player();
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name, "class:", what(p));

// Obj with constructor property overriden.
function OtherPlayer() { console.warn('OtherPlayer constructor called.'); }
OtherPlayer.constructor = new Player();
p = new OtherPlayer();
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name, "class:", what(p));

// Anonymous function obj.
p = new Function("");
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name, "class:", what(p));

// No constructor here.
p = {};
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name, "class:", what(p));

// ES6 class.
class NPC { 
  constructor() {
  }
}
p = new NPC();
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name , "class:", what(p));

// ES6 class extended
class Boss extends NPC {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
p = new Boss();
console.log("constructor:", what(p.constructor), "name:", p.constructor.name , "class:", what(p));
```

**Result:**

[image]

Code: https://jsbin.com/wikiji/edit?js,console

**Update: Dec 04, 2023**

For those needing to grab the class name in IE6 and IE8, `obj.constructor` exists but `name` property doesn't exist. So you need to call `what(obj.constructor)`.

[image]

Comment: literally nothing is available on older browsers if you go back far enough

Comment: @ICW can you be more specific? Anyway, I checked `constructor` property compatibility at https://caniuse.com/?search=constructor and it seems you are right, at least on IE8 this yields `"[object Object]"`

Answer (score 5):

If you use standard IIFE (for example with TypeScript)

```
var Zamboch;
(function (_Zamboch) {
    (function (Web) {
        (function (Common) {
            var App = (function () {
                function App() {
                }
                App.prototype.hello = function () {
                    console.log('Hello App');
                };
                return App;
            })();
            Common.App = App;
        })(Web.Common || (Web.Common = {}));
        var Common = Web.Common;
    })(_Zamboch.Web || (_Zamboch.Web = {}));
    var Web = _Zamboch.Web;
})(Zamboch || (Zamboch = {}));
```

you could annotate the prototypes upfront with

```
setupReflection(Zamboch, 'Zamboch', 'Zamboch');
```

and then use _fullname and _classname fields.

```
var app=new Zamboch.Web.Common.App();
console.log(app._fullname);
```

annotating function here:

```
function setupReflection(ns, fullname, name) {
    // I have only classes and namespaces starting with capital letter
    if (name[0] >= 'A' && name[0] <= 'Z') {
        var type = typeof ns;
        if (type == 'object') {
            ns._refmark = ns._refmark || 0;
            ns._fullname = fullname;
            var keys = Object.keys(ns);
            if (keys.length != ns._refmark) {
                // set marker to avoid recusion, just in case 
                ns._refmark = keys.length;
                for (var nested in ns) {
                    var nestedvalue = ns[nested];
                    setupReflection(nestedvalue, fullname + '.' + nested, nested);
                }
            }
        } else if (type == 'function' && ns.prototype) {
            ns._fullname = fullname;
            ns._classname = name;
            ns.prototype._fullname = fullname;
            ns.prototype._classname = name;
        }
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk637z8q/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var classname = ("" + obj.constructor).split("function ")[1].split("(")[0];
```

Comment: Is there any case in which this would be more accurate than obj.constructor.name? I just don't see any reason for this complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar difficulty and none of the solutions presented here were optimal for what I was working on. What I had was a series of functions to display content in a modal and I was trying to refactor it under a single object definition making the functions, methods of the class.
The problem came in when I found one of the methods created some nav-buttons inside the modal themselves which used an onClick to one of the functions -- now an object of the class. I have considered (and am still considering) other methods to handle these nav buttons, but I was able to find the variable name for the class itself by sweeping the variables defined in the parent window.
What I did was search for anything matching the 'instanceof' my class, and in case there might be more than one, I compared a specific property that was likely to be unique to each instance:

```
var myClass = function(varName)
{
    this.instanceName = ((varName != null) && (typeof(varName) == 'string') && (varName != '')) ? varName : null;

    /**
     * caching autosweep of window to try to find this instance's variable name
     **/
    this.getInstanceName = function() {
        if(this.instanceName == null)
        {
            for(z in window) {
                if((window[z] instanceof myClass) && (window[z].uniqueProperty === this.uniqueProperty)) {
                    this.instanceName = z;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return this.instanceName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient way to get your class name during runtime

`let className = this.constructor.name`

Answer (score 1):

All we need:

1. Wrap a constant in a function (where the name of the function equals the name of the object we want to get)
2. Use arrow functions inside the object

```js
console.clear();
function App(){ // name of my constant is App
  return {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: ()=>{ // very important here, use arrow function 
        console.log(this.constructor.name)
      }
    }
  }
}
}
const obj = new App(); // usage

obj.a.b.c(); // App

// usage with react props etc, 
// For instance, we want to pass this callback to some component

const myComponent = {};
myComponent.customProps = obj.a.b.c;
myComponent.customProps(); // App
```

Comment: You could also bind the function to the object to avoid using arrow functions for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

to get name of class using the class itself.

```js
class Black {
}
// I was search by that and not found in google instade of Black.toString().
console.log(Black.prototype.constructor.name);

// from object ass mentioned by Oleg V. Volkov
const myObj = new Black()
console.log(new Black().constructor.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
  class Root {
    name() {
      return 'Root';
    }
  }

  class Ext1 extends Root {
    name() {
      return 'Ext1';
    }
  }

  class Ext2 extends Ext1 {
    name() {
      return 'Ext2';
    }
  }
 
  root = new Root();
  ext1 = new Ext1();
  ext2 = new Ext2();

  root.name();  // Root
  ext1.name();  // Ext1
  ext2.name();  // Ext2
```

It survives bundlers, and ships the functionality you want.