# Get DHTMLX Grid Cell Type

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

How do I get that object name circled in red (see image).  I've already tried this and it didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314492/3112803

**Details:** I have a DHTMLX grid where cells in a certain column can be a different type per row (either a checkbox or an image).  From what I can tell their API gives you a way to **SET** different types, example: `mygrid.setCellExcellType(rowId,colIdx,"img");` but they don't have a function for **GETTING** the types.  **http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:api_toc_alpha**  I need to determine what type the cell is (and I don't want to do it via looking at the innerHTML).  Look at the attached image from Chrome console.  Those are the objects in the cells.  If I can somehow grab what is circled in red then I could determine the type.  I don't know how to grab that name.

[image]

**UPDATE:** Still not solved. Another forum on this same issue: **http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34217&start=0**

Comment: Based on your post here and at forum.dhtmlx.com I assume you set/change the `GridCellType` via `JavaScript`, right? Wouldn't it be possible to store all changes you made in an 2D array? You could initialize it the moment you create your grid an update it every time you change the `GridCellType` in you grid, too.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It would be possible, thanks for the suggestion, I may do that.  DHTMLX replied back in their forum saying there is no `getCellExcellType()` type of function so I'll either do your suggestion or just keep my try/catch in place.  When I try to do a checkbox action on an image (that used to be a checkbox) it fails, so the try/catch works fine.  I just hate using them as work arounds.  I'd rather do `if(getCellExcellType()==='ch') ...do checkbox stuff...`, but oh well.

Comment: You could outsource you try-catch code into a seperate function like `isCellCheckBox(rowId, cellId)` and use it like this: `if (isChellCheckBox(42,13)) ... do checkbox stuff...`. If you then change you implementation to the way I suggested you just need to change that one function (:

Answer (score 1):

Uhmmmm, in the API there's a function called getColType(cInd).

mygrid.getColType(8) ---> returns i.e. "price"

[GRID API](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid%3aapi_method_dhtmlxgridobject_getcoltype)

Comment: My types are different per row in the same column.  So I need to get the type per cell (a given rowId,colIdx).