# How can i get string with name of object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have some object:

```
var book = {}
book.title = "Big bad book"
book.size = {}
book.size.width = "1 meter"
book.size.height = "2 meter"
```

I want to get something like this

```
nameof(book) // book
nameof(book.size) // book.size
```

or this

```
book.objectName // book
book.size.objectName // book.size
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You can't, if you don't want explicitely set `book.objectName='book';`.

Comment: `book` is the name of a variable referencing your object, not the name of the object.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314338

Comment: i have really much objects so i can't do it your way, Teemu :(

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate question linked in the banner at the top of your question.

Comment: @OrangeFox Why do you want to do that?

Comment: book.*size*.objectName = size. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the object can be retrieved when using a constructor function to create the object:

```
function Book(){
  this.title = "Big bad book"
  this.size = {}
  this.size.width = "1 meter"
  this.size.height = "2 meter"
}

var book = new Book();
console.log(book.constructor.name);
```

Comment: Maybe it's fair to tell, that every instance of `Book` will return the same value, i.e. the name of the constructor function.

Comment: `console.log(book.constructor.name)` **Book** , not a **book**
 ``
`console.log(book.size.constructor.name)` **Object** , not a **book.size**