# Static Method on Enum

Tags: typescript

I have been following [declaration-merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes) for typescript and I copied their example for merging a enum with some functions, and all I did was add `export` to the enum and now I get errors.

```
export enum MyEnum {
  Point = 'Point',
  MultiPoint = 'MultiPoint',
}

namespace MyEnum {
  export function parse(val: string): Type {
    return MyEnum[val as keyof typeof MyEnum];
  }
}
```

`[ts] Individual declarations in merged declaration 'MyEnum' must be all exported or all local. [2395]`

so fair enough it wants all or nothing, so I export out the namespace too.

```
export namespace Type { ... }
```

I now get another error.

`[ts]
Type 'MyEnum | ((val: string) => MyEnum)' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.
  Type '(val: string) => MyEnum' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'. [2322]`

I am not really sure if I am understanding that error message correctly, but it looks like it is trying to say that the MyEnum type can be either be a value of MyEnum **or** function is obviously failing, and also not what I was trying to do.

I also tried to remove the export from `function parse` but then it just becomes unavailable. I have tried adding 'static' in various places but nothing seems to work.

All I am trying to do currently is

```
const value: string = getString();
const pointType = MyEnum.parse(value);
```

But I do plan on having more advanced stuff in the future and would just like to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In adding an extra member to the enum (you are adding `parse` method) you changed the what indexing into the `enum` will produce and what the keys of `enum` will be.

`keyof typeof MyEnum` is going to be `"Point" | "MultiPoint" | "parse"`, so it will include the extra member.

Also `typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum]` will be `MyEnum | ((val: string) => MyEnum)`, including the new member signature.

You can check for parse (which you may want to handle explicitly) :

```
export enum MyEnum {
    Point = 'Point',
    MultiPoint = 'MultiPoint',
}

export namespace MyEnum {
    export function parse(val: string): MyEnum {
        const key = val as keyof typeof MyEnum
        if (key === 'parse') throw new Error("parse !");
        return MyEnum[key]
    }
}
```

Or you can just use an assertion that excludes `parse`:

```
export enum MyEnum {
    Point = 'Point',
    MultiPoint = 'MultiPoint',
}

export namespace MyEnum {
    export function parse(val: string): MyEnum {
        return MyEnum[val as Exclude<keyof typeof MyEnum, 'parse'>]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would I need to do `if (key === parse.name)` rather than `"parse"` due to minification and stuff like that? or am I overthinking it?

Comment: @WORMSS That would not work to narrow the type of `key`. Minification should not impact the name of a publicly exported member usually  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524728/typescript-javascript-minification)