# Should I use a string literal as a type of a returned value in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have utility methods like this:

```
private static getClassName(): 'my-component-class-name' {
    return 'my-component-class-name'
}
```

I use exact return value as the return type and TypeScript compiles it properly, without errors.

Is it a good practice to use this approach or should I put `string` there instead?

To make sure that it's not just ignored, I tried this one and typescript showed me an error:

```
private static getClassName(): 'my-component-class-name' {
    return 'wrong-value'
}
```

Here is the error:

> Type '"wrong-value"' is not assignable to type '"my-component-class-name"'.

[Here is the link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20getClassName()%3A%20'my-component-class-name'%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'wrong-value'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) to TypeScript playground with this code.

Comment: I heven't ever seen something like it. I would stick with string, but that't only because I don't know any benefit that would come from using your syntax.

Comment: No. <br />
You can achieve `getClassName` from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime-in-typescript.

Comment: @serveryang The question is not how to get class name of the constructor but about correctness of using a string literal as a return type as shown above.

Comment: I, for one, would only use string-literal types for enum-like strings (i.e. where strings take a single value from a finite list of accepted values).

Answer (score 0):

Not recommend!

TypeScript is a type clear script, you should use an explicit type as the return type.

TypeScript compiler will create a return type from string literal `'my-component-class-name'` for `getClassName()`, it's a `Type Aliases`, equal to `type returnType = 'my-component-class-name'` and set the `returnType` as the `getClassName()`'s return type. however, the `return 'wrong-value'` is `typeof 'wrong-value'`s type, which is a `string` type, not equal to defined `returnType`.

if you want to let your code build success, just add `| string` after `'my-component-class-name'`. it's an union type.

code snippets:

```
type returnType = "my-component-class-name";
var value: returnType = "my-component-class-name";

type returnType1 = "my-component-class-name" | string;
var value1: returnType1 = "union type";

type returnType2 = true;
var value2 : returnType2 = true;

type returnType3 = 1;
var value3: returnType3 = 1;

class A {
  public static getClassName(): returnType {
    return value;
  }

  public static getClassName1(): returnType1 {
    return value1;
  }

  public static getClassName2(): returnType2 {
    return value2;
  }

  public static getClassName3(): returnType3 {
    return value3;
  }
}

console.log(A.getClassName());
console.log(A.getClassName1());
console.log(A.getClassName2());
console.log(A.getClassName3());
```

the output is:

```
my-component-class-name
union type
true
1
```

Type Aliases doc:  http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html.

Comment: It didn't ignore it because when I put a different string as the return type, it shows me an error.
Look at this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20getClassName()%3A%20'my-component-class-name1'%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'my-component-class-name'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 0):

As described in another answer, the compiler is ignoring your return type. Future compilers might not be so forgiving. If you really want to declare a constant, why not use a constant and not a function? Or, since you want the class name, [get it from the JavaScript runtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314338/get-name-of-object-or-class-in-javascript#10314492)

**Edited to add:** as the comments on that answer point out, `myObj.constructor.name` might not survive minification or other class mangling. I've done things like `getClassName` functions in TypeScript before, but end up refactoring them when I think harder about **why** I want that name. Chances are, you want to call out some trait that isn't well-defined in JavaScript, and which wouldn't survive a refactoring that turns your class into an interface or mixin. So consider calling the method `getXXXType` where `XXX` describes the qualities you're most interested in, for example `getNumericalOperatorType`, `getDateFormattingType`, `getHipaCertificationType`, etc. This will also give you breathing room to add different kinds of types when you discover that your class has taken on [more than one responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).