# Get the Object name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a simple object called "obj1".

```
let obj1 = {
    x: 1,
    y: 5,
    meth: function() {
        return `The result of the ${this} is ${this.x+this.y}`;
    }
};
```

in console, it print

> The result of the [object Object] is 6;

I want to get the `Object` name, which is `obj1` but it gives me `[object Object]`. 
I tried `this.name` but it's showing `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name of object or class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314338/get-name-of-object-or-class-in-javascript)

Comment: @Splinxyy: Close, but that question (which is too broad) was asking for *either* the name of the variable or the constructor function, and the answer addresses the latter. This doesn't ask for that information.

Comment: I actually want the variable name which is "obj1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to get the Object name, which is "obj1"

No, it isn't. Objects don't have names. Your **variable**'s name is `obj1`, but the object's isn't.

There is no practical way for `obj1.meth` to know the name of that variable (other than the programmer hardcoding it, since of course the *programmer* knows the name). That information just isn't provided to `meth`. Note that it would be context-sensitive information:

```
let obj1 = { /*...*/ };
let obj2 = obj1;
obj2.meth(); // Should say...what? "obj1"? "obj2"?
             // (doesn't matter, it can't say either)
```