# Object defaulting to last defined object

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

So I have an object constructor, but when I try and put an object in, the array `cmndlist` always has x amount of the last object defined. (Basically they all end up the same)

```
function command(name, category, help, callback) {
    this.name = name;
    this.help = help;
    this.use = callback;

    cmndlist[category].push(this);
};
```

Here's the code where I define the objects too.

```
command("foo",0,"foo", function(message){
    //code
});

command("bar",1,"bar", function (message){
    //code
}); 

command("foobar",1,"foobar", function (message){
    //code
});
```

So in this example, all the objects in the array will have the same properties as `foobar`.

I don't want that, I want it to have all three of the objects.

Comment: If you're wondering, the first snip-it also appears in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808062/getting-the-name-of-a-defined-object-with-a-constructor

Comment: What is `cmndlist` & why no `new`?

Comment: use the new keyword.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It's an array where the objects reside.

Comment: Answered below. use new keyword.

Comment: If you don't use `new`, `this` is the `window` object, not an instance of your prototype.

Answer (score 1):

To get a new object we need to add the 'new' before our call to the command. Otherwise we are referencing the same object instance each time.
Take a look here for a description of object construction in JavaScript.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

```
var cmndlist = [];

function command(name, category, help, callback) {
    this.name = name;
    this.help = help;
    this.use = callback;

    if(cmndlist.hasOwnProperty(category) == false) cmndlist[category] = [];

    cmndlist[category].push(this);
}; 


new command("foo",0,"foo", function(message){
    //code
});

new command("bar",1,"bar", function (message){
    //code
}); 

new command("foobar",1,"foobar", function (message){
    //code
});
```

Comment: Please explain in the answer what you changed and why it was necessary.

Comment: We need to a 'new' call to create a new object instance, otherwise our call is simply referencing a single object. (Notice the call to command now has new in front). Object are passed by reference (essentially an address pointer to the actual object) So when we add to the array without a call to new, we are just adding a new pointer to the same object.

Comment: Per @Bergi I would consider a syntax more like  let newCommand = new Command(x,y,z); and then append. Will be easy to read and maintain later.

Comment: @PaulThomas "*otherwise our call is simply referencing a single object*" - *which* object is that? Adding that to the explanation would greatly help

Comment: @Bergi added a link to object construction. Kikasuru note in the link it recommends object constructors be named with uppercase. function Command(x,y,z)

Comment: Uh, [w3schools is heavily despised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)...

Comment: @Bergi I have no affinity. Try this instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: Or another useful one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @JohanWentholt snap :)