# Is it possible to get the instanceof operator result as a value?

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a variable that could represent a number of different models (Objects). I want to respond to each differently, ideally through a `switch` statement. Is it possible to get the `instanceof` result as a value?

For example, something like this:

```
function determineModel(model) {
    switch (model instanceof) {  // this does not work
        case 'Foo':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'Bar':
            // do something else
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `model.constructor`? That gives you a reference to the constructor function

Comment: This might give you what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314492/4126658

Answer (score 1):

You can use `model.constructor.name`:

```
switch (model.constructor.name) {
    case "Foo":
        //Do something
    case "Bar":
        //Do something
    default:
        //Default something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
function determineModel(model) {
    switch(model.constructor) {
        case SomeObject:
            console.log('Constructor is SomeObject');
            break;
        case OtherObject:
            console.log('Constructor is OtherObject');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Constructor is ' + model.constructor.name);
        }
    }

determineModel(new OtherObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for `model.constructor.name` and even without the `switch` statement:

```js
function determineModel(model) {
    return {
      Foo: someFnFoo,
      Bar: someFnBar,
    }[model.constructor.name](); // Execute someFn* given the Object's constr. name
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor