# Ensure class property equals name of the class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here [an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2BbbcQAmAEvgQDbQA8AKgHzIDeAUMsmAJ4AOEAXMgM5gooAObIA9OOQALTAHc2mZBBD8ArlBSDhIMQF49yagDoQcbCgD8LGaQoAKBDjyE+1AJR8AbpmAEA3EwAvkxMoJCwiCgYzqSMIUwIZHD8-MjomnCQ1CkA1li4ccDYnBQW4GkxhYQMCUkpaRkQWRA5-PmxhCSEFFDIxaUQ5WCVBS7EdlRNLW0d1QT0zKwc3MiGAETT2Xlj+AAi6xJSK5g20pOOnQR8W607V+7xwUA)

```
interface ICommandHandler<T> {
  type: string // how to ensure string == T.name ?
  handle(command: T): void;
}

interface ICommand {}

class CreateTaskCommand implements ICommand{}

class CreateTaskCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<CreateTaskCommand> {
  type = "CreateTaskCommanD" // typo
  handle(command: CreateTaskCommand) {}
}
```

My goal is to ensure `type` property equals `CreateTaskCommand` string in `CreateTaskCommandHandler`.

My previous example didn't raise a typescript error.

Comment: Given TS is structural typing - it would be unlikely there is any way to obtain a "name" of the type.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can statically check that, but everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314338/get-name-of-object-or-class) is still relevant.

Comment: Is the purpose of the `type` field to conditionally execute some code based on the type of the child interface? If so, there is another way of achieving that.

Comment: @tony yes exactly, I want to ensure I can't create a handler for a command that doesn't exists

Comment: @GuillaumeVincent Would making the type field static and referring to it by the base class work in that case?

Comment: @nit this is what I'm doing, it's just I'm not protecting myself or other dev with writing a typo. I will use the class in the constructor and extract the name instead of asking the developer to write it as a solution

Comment: @GuillaumeVincent There is no room for making a typo if you use a static member, you need to reference the class, you don't write a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use a static property in the command.
Even if you've got a typo, it'll still works.

```
interface ICommandHandler<T> {
  canHandle(command:T): boolean; 
  handle(command: T): void;
}

interface ICommand {
  type: string;
}

class CreateTaskCommand implements ICommand{
  static commandName: string = 'CreateTaskCommand'
  type = CreateTaskCommand.commandName;
}

class CreateTaskCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<CreateTaskCommand> {
  canHandle(command: CreateTaskCommand): boolean {
    return command.type === CreateTaskCommand.commandName;
  }
  handle(command: CreateTaskCommand) {}
}
```