# How to get typescript types in javascript

Tags: javascript

Typeof has some really basic functionality:

`typeof` in JavaScript only returns basic info

`typeof` "Hello World" would return `string`.

`typeof` [1,2,3] would return `object`

I'm looking for a function that I can input like `[1,"string", {property: "object"}]` 
and it would return 
`Array<number | string | object>`
or something like that.

Comment: you could use a replacer function w/json.stringify to iterate and return types

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "*typescript types*"? Maybe point to the relevant TypeScript documentation for what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could roll your own that iterates over each element and determines if it's a distinct `typeof` value, `join`ing the result array into the format you defined:

```js
var improvedTypeOf = (obj) => {
  if (!obj instanceof Array) return typeof obj;
  return "Array<" + obj.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    if (!acc.includes(typeof ele)) acc.push(typeof ele);
    return acc;
  }, []).join(" | ") + ">";
}

console.log(improvedTypeOf([1,"string", {property: "object"}, ]));
```

Comment: This won't work, as there are endless possibilities. What if there is a custom class in the array? I wouldn't want just "object" as the type for the class. I was really just looking to see if there was a lib out there that could work. I'll mark your answer as checked since I don't think there is a good lib out there.

Comment: In that case, instead of getting the `typeof ele` you might consider using its constructor name instead: `ele.constructor.name`. See also: [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314492/269970)