# TypeError: client.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: "voiceStateUpdate",
    run: async (message, client) => {
        client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember, newState) => {
            if (newMember.channel && !oldMember.channel) {
                if (newMember.channelID === "813346805357871154") console.log("dołączono na kanał %s (%s)", newMember.channel.name, newMember.channelID);
            } else if (!newMember.channel && oldMember.channel) {
                console.log("rozłączono z kanału %s (%s)", oldMember.channel.name, oldMember.channelID);
            } else if (newMember.channel && oldMember.channel) {
                console.log("rozłączono z kanału %s (%s) i dołączono do kanału %s (%s)", oldMember.channel.name, oldMember.channelID, newMember.channel.name, newMember.channelID);
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't listen to an event within an event.

Comment: Why are you initializing a new `client` when you're already passing a client through `run: async(message, client)`?

Comment: i deleted it from the beginning and still same error

Comment: message.guild.channels.create(`${client.user.tag}`), {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

-----------error---------

 message.guild.channels.create(`${client.user.tag}`), {
                type: 'voice',
            }

-----code--------

Answer (score 0):

(It depends on how you're calling the module, but) You are probably inverting the names of the `run` arguments and you should replace :

```
run: async (message, client) => {
```

by

```
run: async (client, message) => {
```

if it's not the case, then `run`'s `client` argument is shadowing the `client` variable declared at the beginning of the script and is of a different type.

Check the type of `client`, to be sure you're getting the correct object, by trying something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314492/1789281) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249554/1789281).