# javascript get name of parent object/variable

Tags: javascript, object

Lets say I have

```
var myObject = {

  'myFunction' : function () {
    // something here that lets me get 'myObject'
  }

}
```

I have tried various functions found here and stuff like `this.constructor.name` but i always get 'Object' as the value returned.  Is there any way to get the actual name of the variable in this situation?

edit to explain the *why* so maybe people will better understand...I want to be able to make a function that is continuously called with setInterval.  Something like this:

```
var myObject = {
  'intval' : '',
  'timeout' : 500,

  'start' : function () {
    this.objectName = 'myObject'; // <--I want this to be dynamically popped
    this.intval=window.setInterval("window['"+this.objectName+"'].myFunction()",this.timeout);
  },

  'stop' : function () {
    window.clearInterval(this.intval);
    this.intval='';
  },

  'myFunction' : function () {
    // do something
  }
}
```

This works just fine if i hardcode 'myObject' to this.objectName but I don't want it to be hardcoded. Problem is that I wan't just do `setInterval("window[this.objectName]",100) because`this`is not in the right context when`setInterval` is run, and I don't want to have the objectname hardcoded

Comment: Are you looking for something like `this`, that is some way to refer to the object?

Comment: no, i'm not looking for an object reference, i'm looking for the actual name of the object

Comment: For the edited question: start: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.intval = setInterval(function () {
            that.myFunction();
        }, this.timeout);
    },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way;

```
var myObject = {
    'myFunction' : function () {
        for (var name in window) {
            if (window[name] === this) { 
                alert(name);
                break;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Not very nice IMO, marginally better if you wrap it in your own namespace.

You could also always

```
var myObject = {
    moniker: "myObject",
    ...
```

In light of your update you don't need to resolve the object at all;

```
var myObject = {
    'intval' : '',
    'timeout' : 1500,
    'start' : function () {
        var self = this;
        this.intval = window.setInterval(function() {
            self.myFunction()
        }, this.timeout);
    },
    'myFunction' : function() {
        alert(this.intval);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i was previously just setting a property like your 2nd example

Comment: Updated above, if your prob was the binding of `this` you don't need to resolve the name

Comment: aha! your first example worked fine but that last edit of yours is EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do that in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var name in this.global)
      if (this.global[name] == this) 
        return name
```

[How to get class object's name as a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In short, nope.

The way you're creating your objects, `myObject` is nothing more than a label with a (relatively loose) affiliation with an object literal. In Java or C++ terms, `myObject` is more like a pointer then a class name. If you want a stronger link between the label `myObject` and the object it references, you'll need to use a constructor or subclass pattern. See [this article](http://www.golimojo.com/etc/js-subclass.html) on golimojo.com for a pretty solid overview.