# Getting Object Name from inside the Class (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have a class and I want from inside the class to save as a class variable the name of the object using the class:

```
var xxx = new MyClass(); // on the constructor this.name should be init to "xxx"
```

Ive already tried this approach:

> [How to get class object's name as a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript)

But I can't get it work from the class constructor itself.

Comment: objects don't have names. The object isn't aware of the `xxx` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xxx` is just a variable holding a reference to the `Object` in memory. If you want to give that object a property of name, you should pass it as an argument.

```
var xxx = new MyClass( 'xxx' );

var MyClass = function( name ) {
    this.name = name || undefined;
};
```

You could keep a hash of your objects to avoid creating different variables each time:

```
var myHash = {};

var MyClass = function( name ) {
    if( !name ) throw 'name is required';
    this.name = name;
    myHash[ name ] = this;
    return this;
};
//add static helper
MyClass.create = function( name ) {
    new MyClass( name );
};    

//create a new MyClass
MyClass.create( 'xxx' );

//access it
console.log( myHash.xxx )​;
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9uCe/

Comment: Im bck on the start since accessing the variable name for the object was to evade passing it as an argument, guess no other way! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JuanCB: What if you'd have multiple variables referring to the same object? Or the object is an element in an array only? It just does not work that way.