# How can i get a object's name into string form using JS?

Tags: javascript, object

For example,I have a object here

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

how can i get obj'name to a String "obj"?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: The object doesn't have a name. There is only a variable you defined that is a reference to that object in memory. And since you declared that variable yourself, you should know the name. So just do: `var myString = "obj";`

Comment: @nice why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access the name of the variable.

But, you could use the fact that [functions are first-class objects](http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/) in javascript to your advantage, depending on what your use case is. Since every function object has the "name" property which is set to the name of the function, you could do:

```
var obj = function obj(){ return {a:1,b:2,c:3}; };
console.log("obj.name is: " + obj.name);

> "obj.name is obj"
```

Notice that I assigned a named function to `obj` rather than the more common anonymous function--because anonymous functions do not have a name value.

```
var obj = function(){ return {a:1,b:2,c:3}; };
console.log("obj.name is: " + obj.name); 

> "obj.name is: "
```

*So in this way you have an object with a name value accessible as a string*. But there's a caveat. If you want to access the *value* you have to invoke the function:

```
console.log(obj());

> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

This is because the variable is referencing a function, not the value *returned* by the function:

```
console.log(obj);

> function obj(){ return {a:1,b:2,c:3}; }
```

Note that this technique still doesn't give you the name of the *variable* because you could assign `obj` to another variable named `jbo`:

```
var obj = function obj(){ return {a:1,b:2,c:3}; };
console.log("obj.name is: " + obj.name);
var jbo = obj;
console.log("jbo.name is: " + jbo.name);

> "obj.name is obj"
> "jbo.name is obj"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't. An object may be named by any number of variables, e.g.

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3};
var obj2 = obj;
var otherobj = obj2;
```

All these variables reference the same object -- it doesn't have a specific name.