# property not functioning properly in my custom constructor - Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a custom constructor in Javascript but I can't seem to get why the Console won't log the **'Letters'** property of **"Investigating"** which was created by the constructor **"Verb"**:

```
function Verb (tense, transitivity) {
    this.tense = tense;
    this.transitivity = transitivity;
    **this.letter1 = this.charAt(0);
    this.letter2 = this.charAt(2);
    this.letter3 = this.charAt(4);
    this.Letters = this.letter1 + " " + this.letter2 + " " + this.letter3;**

}

var Investigating = new Verb ("present", "transitive");


console.log(Investigating.tense);  // present
**console.log(Investigating.Letters); //console doesn't log anything**
```

What am I doing wrong here? Would appreciate any help you guys, thanks.

Comment: Basically, I want the console to log I, V, S when I run console.log(Investigating.Letters) and the 0, 2, 4 characters for every new Verb that I create using the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a constructor function `this` refers to the obj being created .so `this.charAt(0)` is incorrect.since Object object does't have charAt method up in its prototype chain.(strings and array has this method).i think you are tryin to do.

```
this.letter1 = this.transitivity.charAt(0);
this.letter2 = this.transitivity.charAt(2);
this.letter3 = this.transitivity.charAt(4);
this.Letters = this.letter1 + " " + this.letter2 + " " + this.letter3;`
```

Comment: Ah, so the Object doesn't have the charAt method... What I actually want to do is to grab the characters at 0, 2, 4 of new objects that are made using this constructor. So I want the console to log I, V, S when I run **console.log(Investigating.Letters)**

Comment: similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789675/how-to-get-class-objects-name-as-a-string-in-javascript