# How do you deal with ASP.NET server callbacks within JavaScript objects?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services, oop

I'm having a problem with using server callbacks to web methods within an object in JavaScript...

```
function myObject() {
     this.hello = "hello";
     var id = 1;
     var name;

     this.findName = function() {
          alert(this.hello); //Displays "hello"
          myServices.getName( id, this.sayHello );
     }

     this.sayHello = function(name) {
          alert(this.hello); //Displays null <-- This is where I'm confused...
          alert(name); //Displays the name retrieved from the server
     }

     this.findName();
}
```

So when a new `myObject` is created, it finds the name and then calls `sayHello` once the name has been found.

The service routine works and returns the correct name.

The issue is that after the name is returned from the server and `this.sayHello` is called, it doesn't seem to be in the same object (no reference to the same `myObject` that we were in when we were finding the name) because `this.hello` gives a `null`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a webservice issue. It's standard javascript functionality. In a callback function, the reference to "this" becomes a reference to the globally scoped "window" object. Here's how you can solve that:

```
function myObject() {
     this.hello = "hello";
     var id = 1;
     var name;
     var self = this; //reference to myObject
     this.findName = function() {
          alert(this.hello); /* Displays "hello" */
          myServices.getName( id, this.sayHello );
     }

     this.sayHello = function(name) {
          alert(self.hello); /* Displays "hello" instead of "undefined" */
          alert(name); /* Displays the name retrieved from the server */
     }

     this.findName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow bind the scope of the `this` object at call time so that the callback will execute within the same scope later.  Currently, your callback function executes in the global window scope as coded, so `this == Window`.  If you are using a framework, they usually provide some way of passing scope as part of the callback to make this easy.

You could also create a closure around the callback parameter, as explained here: [JavaScript Callback Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope)