# Passing a prototype's function as parameter without losing the 'this' context

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes, prototype-programming

I'm defining a '*class*' in JavaScript by means of prototype.

The first time func() runs, it works, but when it's called the second time, through a setTimeout, it fails because this time it has lost the object context, I.E. *this* doesn't reference the object anymore but now references *window*.

Is there a way I can overcome this while still using prototype? or do I need instead to use closures to define a '*class*'?

```
function klass(){}

klass.prototype = {
  a: function() {
    console.log( "Hi" );
  },    
  func: function(){
    this.a();
    setTimeout( this.func, 100 );
  }
};

var x = new klass();
x.func();
```

Comment: Just fyi functions don't have any context on their own, it is resolved every time the function is called and only for that call. So it doesn't matter where and how the function is defined, it only matters how the function is called at a particular time. `x.func()` the function is called as a property of `x`. `var y = {func: x.func}; y.func()` the function is called as a property of `y` and the `this` is `y` for that call. See where I am going with this? setTimeout always calls the function with window set to `this`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Callback Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
setTimeout( this.func.bind(this), 100 );
```

From Mozilla Developer Network:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {  
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {  
    if (typeof this !== "function") {  
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function  
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");  
    }  

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),   
        fToBind = this,   
        fNOP = function () {},  
        fBound = function () {  
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP  
                                 ? this  
                                 : oThis || window,  
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));  
        };  

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;  
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();  

    return fBound;  
  };  
}
```

Comment: An important consideration here: This will only work for browsers with ECMAScript 5 implemented. That means only NEW browsers will work: FF4+, IE9+

Comment: Rather, it is only built-in on those browsers. One can use the above definition otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it in a function:

```
var self = this;  // reference the value of "this"

setTimeout( function() {self.func();}, 100 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Function.prototype.bind`, or wrap your `setTimeout` callback in its own closure:

```
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.a();
        setTimeout( function() {
            self.func();
        }, 100);
    }
```