# JavaScript function fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I'd like to ask somthing that maybe is wrong, but I not sure.

Is there a way to know when a specific function is executed, in order to run a sample of code? I like to make it like an event.

The problem I have is the thick box. I like to resize the thickbox according to the image that display.

To do so, I need to know when the thick box is executed.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Just a note: [thickbox is not maintained any longer](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thickbox use global function, so you could do below: (As @alex suggested.)

```
(function($) {
    var original = tb_show;
    tb_show = function () {
        $(document).trigger('tb_show');
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Then you could bind the event:

```
$(document).bind('tb_show', function() {
    //event handler
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could overload the thickbox plugin invocation.

I'm going to assume it is called on a collection with `thickbox()`, e.g. `$('.container img').thickbox()`.

```
(function($) {

    var original = $.fn.thickbox;

    $.fn.thickbox = function() {
        // Whatever you need to do here.
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Now, when you call...

```
$('.container img').thickbox()
```

...the code will call your new function before handing the control over to the original function.

You can do whatever you want where it says `// Whatever you need to do here.` :)

Comment: unfortunately looks like not working :(. I have try "console.log('Hello');" before the return original.apply(this, artguments); with no response :(

Comment: @MerianosNikos Remember I made an assumption. How do you call thickbox?

Comment: It's ok I know :) xaxaxa. As you see I already have made up rating ;). I have load the WordPress default Thickbox implementation, that now allowing me to resize it. :(

Answer (score 2):

I am not a JS developer but you can create a callback function and make it execute when that specific function is executed.

You can find a good explanation here: [JavaScript Callback Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope)

Comment: This can be done without affect the source code of the thickbox plugin ?