# Objects mocked with Sinon.js do not acknowledge having their methods executed via a jQuery.delegate callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

Basically, if you mock an object using Sinon.js which has a property that's passed as callback to jQuery.delegate your mock expectations will fail when you trigger the method being observed in jQuery.delegate. If you execute the method inside of the body of an anonymous function that you use as the callback to jQUery.delegate your expectations will pass.

```
test("FAILS: Handler is invoked as callback from jQuery delegate method directly...", function() {
    var Controller,
        View,
        $el,
        c,
        v,
        mock;

    Controller = function() {
        var self = {};

        self.handler = function(e) {
            console.log("got handled");
        };

        return self;
    };

    View = function($el, controller) {
        var self = {};

        self.render = function() {
            $el.html("");

            $el.delegate("#derp", "keyup", controller.handler);
        };

        return self;
    };

    $el  = jQuery("");
    c    = new Controller();
    v    = new View($el, c);
    mock = this.mock(c);

    v.render();

    mock.expects("handler").once();

    $el.find("input").val("bar").trigger("keyup");
    equal($el.find("input").val(), "bar"); // passes!

    mock.verify();
});
```

```
test("WINS: Handler is invoked inside anonymous function...", function() {
    var Controller,
        View,
        $el,
        c,
        v,
        mock;

    Controller = function() {
        var self = {};

        self.handler = function(e) {
            console.log("got handled");
        };

        return self;
    };

    View = function($el, controller) {
        var self = {};

        self.render = function() {
            $el.html("");

            $el.delegate("#derp", "keyup", function(e) {
                controller.handler(e);
            });
        };

        return self;
    };

    $el  = jQuery("");
    c    = new Controller();
    v    = new View($el, c);
    mock = this.mock(c);

    v.render();

    mock.expects("handler").once();

    $el.find("input").val("bar").trigger("keyup");
    equal($el.find("input").val(), "bar"); // passes!

    mock.verify();
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks,

Erin

Comment: Have to agree, if v2 works then so should v1. Does v1 also fail with an actual keyup? Does v1 also fail when tested with `.triggerHandler("keyup")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic [callback scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope) gotcha. Function arguments are out of scope, so `controller` does not have a `handler` method since it is not defined locally. The anonymous function gives it scope because functions control scope in JavaScript.