# Accessing to object itself by using "this" after binding it's function to an event

Tags: javascript, oop, object

When I try access to the object with "this" keyword, I am getting the "window" object instead of object's itself because I bind it's function to an event and that event belongs to window object.

In the example, `alert(this.osd)` says that it is undefined because there is no "osd" in the "window" object. So, what is the best way to solve this ? Defining the game object as window.game ?

```
var game = {

    osd : null,
    stage : null,

    tick : function(){
        alert(this.osd);

    },

    init : function(){

        // Configure the OSD
        this.osd = "a";

        // Preapare the stage;
        this.stage = "b";
        window.addEventListener("click",this.tick);
    }
}

game.init();
```

Comment: Closure, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('click', this.tick.bind(this))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the tick method with the object context like this:

```
var self = this;
window.addEventListener("click", function() {self.tick()});
```

Or, you could use `.bind()` in modern browsers which does essentially the same thing (it creates a stub function that calls the actual method with the right object context).

```
window.addEventListener("click", this.tick.bind(this));
```

---

The issue is that when you pass `this.tick` to `addEventListener()`, you are only passing a function reference to the tick function, you aren't actually passing the object reference.  So, when addEventListener() calls tick without any object reference, the default value of `this` for a function call without an object reference is `window` (when not in strict mode) so that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. =)

Answer (score -1):

You can bind using a closure, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('click',(function(o){return function(){o.tick()}})(this));
```

Also, (unrelated to your problem), since you're making an initialiser function, you would be better off using a class/instance setup:

```
function Game( myParameter ) {
    this.osd = "a";
    this.tick = function( ) {
    }
    window.addEventListener('click',(function(o){return function(){o.tick()}})(this));
}
var game = new Game( 3 );
```

Notice that `game` is now created with `new`, and we can pass parameters to its "constructor" function.

Comment: "`game` is not a true object in that code" yes it is. It's declared with an object literal.

Comment: game is too a real object with methods.

Comment: @zzzzBov et al. Yes, ok. I missed the problem (now edited). It isn't a real object though (as far as OOP goes); prototype definitions need the `new` keyword, for example.

Comment: Objects can be created with a static declaration too just like the `game` object in the OP's code.  You seem to be under the false impression that a statically declared object isn't a real object.  That's just wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know it's an object, and will function perfectly well in this case, but (in my opinion) it's a bad practice, because it is *not* an OOP object. It doesn't conform to the standard class/instance setup, and will not support prototypes.

Comment: @jfriend00 taking what you said into account, I have adjusted the language of my comments.