# JavaScript Event in Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript class. I have one JavaScript class. What I want is in `console.log` will output result of class object not this element (element that mousedown). How can I write that?

```
function Transformer (output) {
    this.output = output;
    $(output+' .object').mousedown(function(e){
        console.log(this);
    });
}

var test = new Transformer('.console');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the class object itself, you need to save a reference to the context in another variable, because `this` in the anonymous function points to the context of the anonymous function itself:

```
function Transformer (output) {
    var self = this;
    this.output = output;

    $(output+' .object').mousedown(function(e){
        console.log(self); // will print the object itself
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to skip saving a reference altogether:

```
function Transformer (output) {
    this.output = output;

    $(output+' .object').mousedown(e => {
        console.log(this); // will print the object itself
    });
}
```

Comment: Simple and acceptable. I prefer your answer while i can access both element and class object. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a lot (like e.g. [JavaScript Callback Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope)) but I thought I should mention that this can also be resolved using arrow functions in ECMAScript 6 like below:

```
function Transformer (output) {
   this.output = output;
   $(output+' .object').mousedown((e) => {
       console.log(this);
   });
}

var test = new Transformer('.console');
```

However using arrow functions means you are losing the event target context (which you can probably recover using `e.currentTarget`

I am mentioning this because chances are all the sources are older than ES 6 and might not mention this.

Check [ES6 compatibility](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for platforms that currently support arrow functions.

Comment: thank for answer but for @31piy's i can access both element and class object.