# Here API clustering error: "addLayer is not defined"

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am try to use clastering in my aplication but I am get a error addLayer is not defined".

I have no Idea how to resolve this issue.

I just copy and paste this sample function from Here API samples api clusters

And I'm passing lat and lng, to the function but addLayer is undefined.

I have the map object, but the addLayer is undefined.

```
function startClustering(map, data) {
  // First we need to create an array of DataPoint objects,
  // for the ClusterProvider
  var dataPoints = data.map(function(item) {
    return new H.clustering.DataPoint(item.latitude, item.longitude);
  });

  // Create a clustering provider with custom options for clusterizing the input
  var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
    clusteringOptions: {
      // Maximum radius of the neighbourhood
      eps: 32,
      // minimum weight of points required to form a cluster
      minWeight: 2
    }
  });

  // Create a layer tha will consume objects from our clustering provider
  var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);

  // To make objects from clustering provder visible,
  // we need to add our layer to the map

  map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);

}
```

And I'm passing lat and lng, to the function but addLayer is undefined.

I have the map object, bust does not exist addLayer.

I'm embed the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-clustering.js"></script>
```

on my index.

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

If someone knows how to resolve I'm glad to listen

**EDIT:** Additional code per comment request:

```
function addMarkerToCameraGroup(map, coordinate, html) { // add and remove markers
  document.querySelector(".camera-box").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("camera-marker-position")[0] === undefined) {
      map.addObject(cameraMarker);
      self.startClustering(map, coordinate);
    } else {
      map.removeAll();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the `map` argument that you're passing? Better yet, can you just include the code where you call this function? Sounds like you might be passing in the wrong type. From [the documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html), it looks like  `addLayer` would require `map` to be of type `H.map`.

Comment: I am calling the function startClustering(map, cords) from my function addDomMarker(map) and pass the map as argument

Comment: That is my code `function addMarkerToCameraGroup(map, coordinate, html) {  
  // add and remove markers  
  document.querySelector(".camera-box").addEventListener("click", function(){
   if(document.getElementsByClassName("camera-marker-position")[0] === undefined) {
    //map.addObject(cameraMarker);
    self.startClustering(map, coordinate);
   } else {
    map.removeAll();
   } 
  });
 }`

Comment: The code you've provided still does not explicitly reveal what `map` is One of the the methods you're calling (`map.addObject()`) is listed in the documentation for `H.map`, however the other (`removeAll()`) is *not*. Please post the code where you first declare `map`.

Comment: Sorry, I have `
 map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map, {
   center: {
    lat: -19.9211375,
    lng: -43.9490617,
   },
   zoom: 6
  });   `

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question a second time as: ["Try to create a cluster unsing a sample but addLayer got undefinied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899752/try-to-create-a-cluster-unsing-a-sample-but-addlayer-got-undefinied) which doesn't include some of the details in this question.  Given the additional edit / context you made on this question however, it would seem you are adding an event listener in which `map` is probably out of scope or not yet defined for visibility inside the anonymous function.

```
document.querySelector(".camera-box").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("camera-marker-position")[0] === undefined) {
      map.addObject(cameraMarker);
      self.startClustering(map, coordinate);
    } else {
      map.removeAll();
    }
  });
```

You could do a typing check to see if map has been defined when the click event occurs and/or confirm whether it is an `H.map`.  Without seeing the full listing, it may also be the case that you have not made `map` a global variable but instead declared it somewhere else in the page initialization so is out of scope when the click event is fired.

You can check [JavaScript callback scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope) for details on closures where you could provide the `map` to the event when declaring the function. For more general information: [JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: Yes the problem is the scope, send the current scope to the function, but I got another error, referring to scope, return a (return indexOf(a) this) Also without scope context