# Rhino: Cannot modify a property of a sealed object

Tags: javascript, rhino

Using Rhino 1.7.6, this script works:

```js
input = [ { foo: [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ] } ];
var output = [];
input.forEach(function (obj) {
    obj.foo.forEach(function(s) { output.push(s); });
});
```

but this one does not:

```js
input = [ { foo: [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ] } ];
var output = [];
input.forEach(function (obj) {
    obj.foo.forEach(output.push);
});
```

instead, throwing this exception on line 4:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Cannot modify a property of a sealed object: 0.
```

Why?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: It isn't related to Rhino, it is how JS behaves: `this` lost its context (try in a browser). Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Callback Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183214/javascript-callback-scope)

Comment: So in other words, the plain expression `output.push` returns a function that has "forgotten" that it was ever associated with `output`... That would explain it. Thanks!